# can't login in lightdm (16.10) with xdmcp

Tags: login, lightdm, login-screen, 16.10, xdmcp

Using Xming from a Windows I can get the lighdm login screen. After introducing the right password, the Xserver window goes grid gray and then the login screen is shown again. Any clue? (thanks in advance)

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Followed the instructions provided on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/xdmcp to setup XDMCP. I can connect to it with Xephyr, I get the usual login screen, I type in valid credentials. The screen blinks black, then puts me back to the login screen.

Comment: Try with creating new user. If that works, and you can log in, rename your home folder to something like username.old and create new homefolder  for your username and copy all content with `cp -a /username.olf/. /username/`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I fixed it by:

```
sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.backup
sudo service lightdm restart
```